# How do I enable OAuth in Node/Express without maintaining sessions

Tags: javascript, authentication, oauth, passport.js

I have used `Passport.js` previously but that requires to make a session to enable authentication and serializes user details on it, but if I have to implement `oAuth` without using `Passport.js`, what will be the right approach?

Comment: You could use JWTs. Here's an article that outlines an implementation with passport.js: https://scotch.io/@devGson/api-authentication-with-json-web-tokensjwt-and-passport

Comment: @JustinSmith Thanks for the link. Please upvote if you consider the question genuine for a novice dev. Thanks :)